# Rails: changing params through js / jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails project I'm using `pg_search` in combination with `select2`. I have a form with autocomplete and what I'd like to achieve is the `params` updating when the user selects an option, and not only on the `submit`. Is it possible to dynamically change params with jQuery?

I'm thinking of something like:

**in my view:**

```
%form{action: "/bops/new"}
  %label Search by company name
  %select{name: "term", onchange: 'myFunction()', autofocus: true }
```

**js script**

```
:javascript
  function myFunction() {
    { # change my params[:id] to the id of selected record }
  }
```

I know that the onchange function is triggered correctly as right now I'm using it to display the 'select' button when user selected a record but I'd like to get rid of the button completely.

Comment: I haven't used Rails-only in a while,  but when you say "change the params", do you mean execute an AJAX request to the Rails back-end with the new search term when you type something, so the auto-complete populates for the new search term?

Comment: give an id="blabla' to form and  jquery part `$(this).parent('#blabla').submit()`